# How do I compress multiple files into a .xz archive?

Tags: compression

I want to compress several images into a .xz archive. How do I do that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Although `tar cJf archive files...` as [detailed by Zacharee1](https://askubuntu.com/a/610006/22949) and [by heemayl](https://askubuntu.com/a/610008/22949) is usually what you'll want to do, another way is to pipe tarred data to the [`xz`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/en/man1/xz.1.html) command:

```
tar c files... | xz > archive.tar.xz
```

Since Ubuntu's [`tar`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/en/man1/tar.1.html) supports the `J` option, this alternate way is specifically useful when you wish to pass options to `xz`.

In this example, I tar and xzip some TIFF files with a high level of compression (`-9` to `xz`) and verbose output (`v` to `tar`, `-v` to `xz`):

```
ek@Io:~/Pictures$ tar vc *.tif{,f} | xz -9v > pics.tar.xz
page001.tif
page002.tif
page003.tif
page004.tif
page9087.tif
page3la.tiff
quux0000.tiff
  100 %       207.3 KiB / 290.0 KiB = 0.715
```

This could, of course, also be done in two explicitly separate steps:

```
ek@Io:~/Pictures$ tar vcf pics.tar *.tif{,f}
page001.tif
page002.tif
page003.tif
page004.tif
page9087.tif
page3la.tiff
quux0000.tiff
ek@Io:~/Pictures$ xz -9v pics.tar
pics.tar (1/1)
  100 %       207.3 KiB / 290.0 KiB = 0.715
```

Those two ways are not actually equivalent in how they operate, though the `.tar.xz` files they produce in the end should be the same (and were, when I tested it).

- In the first, the [output](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_.28stdout.29) of `tar` is [piped](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_%28Unix%29) (`|`) to the [input](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_input_.28stdin.29) of `xz`. `xz` receives data from `tar` almost immediately, and no intermediate uncompressed tar file is ever created. This is to say that the first way is essentially equivalent [to `tar cJf archive files...`](https://askubuntu.com/a/610006/22949), except for the additional arguments passed to `xz`.
- In the second, an uncompressed tar archive is created by the first command, then compressed by `xz` in the second command. (`xz` automatically deletes the original file when it's done, unless invoked with `-k`/`--keep`.)

For further reading, see [this post by Rafael van Horn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27785347/1038860) and the `tar` and `xz` manpages.

Comment: +1..this is a good one when higher (or varying) compression ratio is desired..

Comment: Hello 2015! Another way you can accomplish varying compression levels using `tar -J` is to specify the environment variable `XZ_OPT`, making the invocation something like: `XZ_OPT="-9v" tar -Jcf out.tar.xz [files]`

Comment: @Wug That's an excellent idea. It seems to me that it warrants its own separate answer. Are you willing to post that?

Answer (score 13):

Use `tar` with `-J` option:

```
tar -cvJf images.tar.xz /directory/containing/images/*
```

`tar` is used to combine multiple files into one (Archive) and then we need to compress the archive using XZ compression algorithm.

From [`man tar`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/tar.1.html):

```
-c, --create
       create a new archive
-v, --verbose
       verbosely list files processed
-J, --xz

-f, --file ARCHIVE
       use archive file or device ARCHIVE
```

Also note that `images.tar.xz` will be created in the current directory, if you want to save it somewhere else use `/full/path/to/images.tar.xz`.

Comment: started the process of xzing several huge PSDs and to be honest, the archive is offering some huge compression! 400 MB+ is now 200MB

Comment: great..although `xz` is the slowest among `xz`, `gzip`, `bzip2` due to its higher compression ratio than the others..the slowness is worth to deal with if you want more compression..

Comment: My psds in total are, like, 600-900 MB total xD

Comment: you are good to go....

Comment: some kinda error ._.

Comment: Whats the error say?

Comment: I don't remember but I'm doing it again and I'll see this time

Comment: hold on..before running, remove the compressed file otherwise all items will be added to it rather than creating a new one....or give the compressed file a different name..

Comment: crap! its the same name!

Comment: No problem..stop it and run it with a different name or remove it..

Comment: i saved in in a different directory :)

Comment: It worked this time

Answer (score 3):

Use this command: `tar cJf <archive.tar.xz> <files>`. Separate file paths with a space.

Comment: you need this: `-cfJ`

Comment: @A.B.: you don't need `-` in front..from `man tar`: `A
     function letter need not be prefixed with ``-''` ..so `tar cJf` is absolutely OK.

Comment: @heemayl But it does not seem to be working. I tried it without the '-', but tar is not completed.

Comment: @heemayl That's what I thought.

Comment: @A.B.: then it might be a mistake somewhere else..

Comment: The mistake was '*': `tar cfJ archive.tar.xz *`. This works: ` `tar cfJ archive.tar.xz <file_name>`

Comment: @A.B. What? That looks exactly the same.

Comment: Now its wrong..the `-f` option indicates a file name to be followed next, its not happening when you use `tar -cfJ <archive.tar.xz> <files>` ....you need `tar -cJf <archive.tar.xz> <files>`

Comment: @A.B. Ah. Makes sense.

Comment: Note that you should stick with your first answer `tar cJf`, that would give OP another way of doing this as my answer already covered `tar --cvJf` at first..

Comment: @heemayl What do you mean?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/610024/confusion-about-tar :)

Comment: I meant check [my answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/610008/216503), it already uses the format you are using currently in your answer..you should go back to your earlier format i.e. post the answer without leading `-` as `tar cJf`

Comment: @heemayl OK. I shall.